# Two users publish to one blog? on drupal5

Tags: drupal

Is it possible to have two users publish two one blog instead of two separate blogs? or is there a way to combine two blogs into one feed/url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Drupal user gets their own blog, that's just the way the Blog module works.

However, you could use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to aggregate the blogs together into a single feed - showing both blogs as interleaved posts at a particular URL, and creating a combined RSS feed that lists all the posts.

Side note: With the Q1 2011 release of Drupal 7, support for the older Drupal 5 ceased. In particular, there won't be any new security patches. Moving to Drupal 6 (at least) or Drupal 7 (if you can) is strongly recommended.